# In gRPC web, how do you abort a call and make an early return through an interceptor?

Tags: grpc, grpc-web

### The problem

I've written an interceptor to cancel a gRPC-web method call, but I couldn't find a way to make an early return. Assuming I want to return a cache instead. When the call is cancelled in the interceptor, the callback function doesn't get run.

### What I've tried

I've tried to call the cancel method inside the interceptor. However, when cancel is called, the callback function doesn't run and nothing gets returned.

**Edit 1**: Per Developer's answer, added lines to return cached response on eventType = data and moved the cancel call inside. However, when `stream.cancel()` is in the interceptor, the callback inside `client.hello` doesn't get run.

Here's the interceptor:

```js
const StreamInterceptor = function () {};
StreamInterceptor.prototype.intercept = function (request, invoker) {
  const InterceptedStream = function (stream) {
    this.stream = stream;
  };
  InterceptedStream.prototype.on = function (eventType, callback) {
    if (eventType === 'data') {
      // added to return cache
      callback({ message: 'world' });
      this.stream.cancel();
      return this;
    }
    this.stream.on(eventType, callback);
    return this;
  };
  const stream = invoker(request);
  return new InterceptedStream(stream);
};
```

Here's the client and the method call. The call is unary.

```js
const client = new ServiceClient('http://localhost:8080', null, {
  streamInterceptors: [new StreamInterceptor()],
});
client.hello(message, {}, (err, res) => {
  console.log(res);
});
```

### What I'm expecting

The goal is to be able to cancel the call and return a cached response.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for asking! I've replied in this thread below, and will follow-up there. Thanks!

https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/ee8LeqrYXxI